# Chrome Extension - Get page source when fully loaded (client side content too)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome Extension where I need to retrieve the source code of a newly create tab.

Retrieving the source code is not a problem as such, my script below does that perfectly but what I'm looking for is to get the source code once the page has been completely loaded included dynamic content that has been inserted after page load (like with Ajax for example).

To get the source code, I'm using

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, 
    {
        file: 'test.js',
    }, function(results) 
    {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE

    }
```

test.js contains the following:

```
function DOMtoString(document_root) {
var html = '',
    node = document_root.firstChild;
while (node) {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
    case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        html += node.outerHTML;
        break;
    case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        html += node.nodeValue;
        break;
    case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
        html += '<![CDATA[' + node.nodeValue + ']]>';
        break;
    case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
        html += '<!--' + node.nodeValue + '-->';
        break;
    case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
        // (X)HTML documents are identified by public identifiers
        html += "<!DOCTYPE " + node.name + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '') + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '') + '>\n';
        break;
    }
    node = node.nextSibling;
}
return html;
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
action: "getSource",
source: DOMtoString(document),
metadata: shop_metadata
});
```

What I would like to do is to retrieve the source code only when a class has been detected and if it failed after a couple of seconds, the script should skip the process. The class I'm looking for is available in the "shop_metadata" variable.

Is there a way to make that happen with SendMessage like in my script?

I have tried to do this:

```
function test (document)
{

    var checkExist = setInterval(function() 
        {
            if ($('.product-title').length) 
                {
                    console.log("Exists!");
                    source = DOMtoString(document);
                    console.log(source);
                    return source;
                    clearInterval(checkExist);

                }
        }, 5000);

}
```

and then modify my message:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
action: "getSource",
source:test(document),
metadata: shop_metadata
});
```

If I executed this in the console, I get the source code with the dynamic content but when I checked the content of "source" in the extension, it returns "undefined"

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: It works most of the time but not with sites loading content through Ajax after page load.

Comment: `return source;` does nothing useful because it's inside a setInterval callback. Replace it with sendMessage.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add a sendMessage but the listener never gets the answer: var checkExist = setInterval(function() 
 {
  if ($('.product-title').length) 
   {
    console.log("Exists!");
    source = DOMtoString(document);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source:"aaa",
    metadata: shop_metadata
    });
    
    clearInterval(checkExist);
   }
 }, 5000);

Comment: I don't see any listener in the posted code. See documentation for  chrome.runtime.onMessage.

Comment: indeed, the listener is in another js file: chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender) 
  {
   if (request.action == "getSource") 
    {

     
     source = request.source;
     parser = new DOMParser();
     content = parser.parseFromString(source, "text/html");
        console.log(content);
     // GET FIRST TITLE
     title1 = shop_metadata["title1"];
     console.log('Get: '+title1);
     titles = $(title1,content).contents();
     
     console.log(titles);
    }
  });

Comment: If the listener is inside the popup, it will be destroyed when the popup is closed, which happens if you open a new tab without specifying `active: false`.

Comment: The listener is in popup.js (called from popup.html) and tabs are created with active:false. The listener works fine with the first version of the code (in my original post). As soon as I use setinterval, the listener doesn't work anymore, it's like the send message from within the setinterval is not working. I tried a setinterval with static values to avoid having scope issue but still, the listener doesn't get anything.

Comment: It might be a bug in Chrome in case you don't have `"permissions": ["<all_urls>"]`. Try in Firefox or an older portable version of Chrome, or in Chrome Canary.

Comment: Thanks! The issue seems to come from the sendMessage that doesn't wait until the setinterval has done its job before sending the data to the listener.